# Add entire data set to local storage

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having trouble adding a data set to local storage. I am only able to add 1 option at the moment with the following code

```
const medicalPlansArr = medicalAidPlans[0].selectedMAP.map((x, index) => ({ label: x.options[index].optionName, value: x.options[index].id }));

localStorage.setItem('medicalPlans', JSON.stringify(medicalPlansArr));
```

This is how the data set looks and thje only values i want to store is the `optionName` and `id`

```
[
    {
      "selectedMAP": [
        {
          "mapName": "Default",
          "options": [
            {
                id: 1,
                optionName: 'Hospital Plan',
                memberAmount: 1850,
                adultDependantAmount: 900,
                childDependantAmount: 900
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                optionName: 'Savings Plan',
                memberAmount: 2200,
                adultDependantAmount: 1100,
                childDependantAmount: 1100
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                optionName: 'Elite Plan',
                memberAmount: 4900,
                adultDependantAmount: 2200,
                childDependantAmount: 2200
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Any ideas why it doesn't store all the required values?

Comment: Your index is off of the outer selectedMAP, not the options.  there is only one index for that outer array

Answer (score 0):

I think reintializing in your case please pusj in any array your require field first then save in localstorage

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to using a for loop and push. Not sure if it's the best approach but this is where I got to.

```
let medicalPlansArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < medicalAidPlans[0].selectedMAP[0].options.length; i++) {
 medicalPlansArr.push({"label": medicalAidPlans[0].selectedMAP[0].options[i].optionName, "value": medicalAidPlans[0].selectedMAP[0].options[i].id})
}

localStorage.setItem('medicalPlans', JSON.stringify(medicalPlansArr));
```